# Spectral radius in Banach Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra and $a\in A$ and $\lambda \in \rho(a)$. I want to prove that $$r(R(a,\lambda))=\frac{1}{d(\lambda,\sigma(a))}.$$ where $R(a,\lambda)=(\lambda 1-a)^{-1}$ and $r(.)$ is the spectral radius.
I'm giving this hint: prove the result if $A$ is commutative then do it for the general case.
 I'm trying to do this but the only thing that I can prove is $\|R(a,\lambda)\|\ge\frac{1}{d(\lambda,\sigma(a))}$, but since $r(.)\le \|.\|$ things don't add up. and when dealing with the general case a'm not sure how to go from the commutative case to the general case I have a feeling that this has to do with $r(.)$ being upper semi continuous. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What is $r(R(a,\lambda))$? Actually, what is $R(a,\lambda)$? Is it $a-\lambda 1$?

Comment: @julien $R(a,\lambda)=(\lambda 1-a)^{-1}$ and $r(R(a,\lambda)$ is the spectral radius of $R(a,\lambda)$

Comment: Ah, ok, of course. Maybe you could add that in your question.

Comment: @julien will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to assume $A$ commutative.
Consider the holomorphic function 
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{\lambda -z}
$$
on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\lambda\}$, which is an open neighborhood of the spectrum $\sigma(a)$ of $a$.
The holomorphic functional calculus makes sense of
$$
f(a)=(\lambda 1-a)^{-1}.
$$
and yields, by spectral mapping:
$$
\sigma(f(a))=f(\sigma(a)).
$$
Therefore
$$
r(f(a))=\max_{\beta\in \sigma(f(a))}|\beta|=\max_{\alpha \in \sigma(a)}|f(\alpha)|=\max_{\alpha\in\sigma(a)}\frac{1}{|\lambda-\alpha| }=\frac{1}{\min_{\alpha\in \sigma(a)}|\lambda-\alpha|}=\frac{1}{d(\lambda,\sigma(a))}
$$
where $d(\lambda,\sigma(a))=\inf_{\alpha\in \sigma(a)} |\lambda -\alpha|=\min_{\alpha\in \sigma(a)} |\lambda -\alpha|$ by compactness of the spectrum.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but is this the case for commutative Banach algebra or does this proof also work for the non-commutative case?

Comment: @iam It suffices to work in the algebra generated by $a$, which is commutative.

Comment: can you tell me why it is sufficient to show the result for algebra generated by a?

Comment: You don't even need to mention the algebra generated by $a$, actually. Everything I used is true in a general complex unital Banach algebra. Functional calculus, spectral mapping theorem...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra

Comment: thank you for your help, this subject is new to me and i'm having a hard time grasping it. thank you again.

Comment: @i.a.m You're most welcome.

Comment: @i.a.m - I found this problem to much simpler with the reduction to the commutative case.  You can use Proposition II.2.12 to get what you want.  To justify the reduction to the commutative case, you can use Corollary III.1.10.

Comment: @Kyle, Will try it, thank you.

Comment: pardon my error, of course its not Corollary III.1.10, but the problem from the previous assignment that is used for the reduction, I'm sure you noticed this already

Comment: @i.a.m I don't know if you are still around: note my answer had a wrong argument. It should be correct now.